# Best way to create and manage someone's triggers (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I wrote some GAS code for a person and it required a trigger.

I created this line and asked the person to call it to set up his trigger (as it is his spreadsheet):

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").timeBased().everyDays(1).inTimezone("Australia/Brisbane").atHour(5).create()
```

But then, I cannot see his trigger.

To see if a trigger is there I used:

```
Logger.log(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers())
```

It returned an empty array so looks like the trigger is gone but I don't see it physically...

So, if it's a client, it is not cool to ask his "please set up your trigger" and then not be able to see it and then ask to check if it's there.

What's the best way to set up and manage triggers for clients?

Comment: Seems like you should be able to get the trigger's info with `getProjectTriggers()`. Please, clarify, under whose authority the `Logger.log()` is run - user's or yours (if *user* created the trigger and *you* run the getter, you will end up with an empty `Array`)?

Comment: another user created the trigger, I don't see it physically.

Comment: Can I create a trigger that would be visible for all users?

Comment: please, take a look at TheMaster's thorough answer - user creating the trigger and you trying to access it is the exact reason `getProjectTriggers()` does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see his triggers, open the editor and choose "Current Project Triggers" from the Edit menu.

On the trigger page, click the "x" on the "Owned by me" filter. Then you shold see all the triggers for the project and know if it is set up. It won't tell you who owns it, I don't think.

You cannot "manage" his triggers from there, just see them. There is no way to mess with other peoples triggers (a much debated topic!) but you can change the name of the function to break a trigger.

Comment: Girl, you rock! It gave me some information, thanks.

Comment: I can also see its id there.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** As stated in the accepted answer, It seems other user's triggers are viewable manually in the [dashboard](https://script.google.com/home/triggers).

---

Other user's triggers are not available for you to view programmatically/manually for security reasons.

> I created this line and asked the person to call it to set up his trigger (as it is his spreadsheet):

You must  explicitly create a menu , so that the user may click on it to create the trigger:
If the user sets up a trigger through menu options, You can set the id of trigger to properties service like this.

```
function createTrigger(){ //to be linked to a "Create Trigger" menu

// Creates an edit trigger for a spreadsheet identified by ID.
var tid = ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunion')
    .forSpreadsheet('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqc3')
    .onEdit()
    .create()
    .getUniqueId();

//set id of trigger in properties 
PropertiesService
    .getScriptProperties() //if you want public access to trigger(If not use getUserProperties)
    .setProperty(
        Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() || 
            ('user1 ' + Math.random().toFixed(3)),
        tid
    );

//Inform user: trigger created successfully.
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Trigger created successfully with id: ' + tid);
//@see https://script.google.com/home/triggers
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That's a helpful thing!